# Trouble creating folder in lua over all platforms

Tags: lua, filesystems, love2d

I'm making a game in Love2d and it uses a tile maps for it's environments, alongside the game I'm also making an application to create these tile maps and that's where the trouble comes in.

What I want to do is create a folder in My Documents (or Documents on Mac and Linux) but this want for portability is the problem, I had a working version where it used luajit's ffi and `_mkdir` but `_mkdir` doesn't work on platforms other than Windows. I tried `mkdir` for other platforms and tested it on a Macbook Air but nothing happened.

Love's filesystem library doesn't work outside of the Love2d path so I can't use that. I don't know how to include a C library in the application that's compatible with Love and would work outside my machine so unless someone can help me with that then that idea's out the window.

Should I just make it compatible with Windows machines? That would be the easy way around the problem but it doesn't seem very user friendly, but I doubt anyone is going to make maps for the game anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local function create_dir_inside_documents_folder()
   if (os.getenv("oS") or ""):match("^Windows") then
      os.execute('mkdir "%userprofile%\\Documents\\Your folder" 1>nul: 2>&1')
   else
      os.execute('mkdir -p ~/Documents/"Your folder" 2>/dev/null')
   end
end
```

P.S.
If "My Documents" folder on Windows was moved from default location to user-specified path, you have to look into registry to get this path
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\Personal`

Comment: Works on both OS X and Windows, not tested on linux, thanks!